# open and parse multiple gpx files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gpx

I am trying to parse multiple gpx files stored in a directory with gpxpy in Python and create a pandas data frame.

Here is my code:

import gpxpy

```
import os

# Open the file in read mode and parse it
gpx_dir = r'/Users/Gav/GPX Data/'
for filename in os.listdir(gpx_dir):
        gpx_file = open(filename, 'r')
        gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I know the gpx file is fine as I am able to open it and parse it as a single file, but as soon as I try to open multiple gpx files it gives this error.

Comment: you may like tihs tool: https://github.com/nidhaloff/gpx_converter

Answer (score 1):

ok after lots of digging around  fixed the problem myself...turns out there was .DS_store file in my data folder which was a hidden and auto generated file and it caused the issue. I was able to fix the problem after removing it.